# How to remove labels from ggplot donut in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have visualized some data as a donut chart. Here is the code:

```
ggplot(region_average, aes(ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=4, xmin=3, fill=state_code)) +
  geom_rect() +
  geom_label_repel( x=3.5, aes(y=labelPosition, label=label), size=3) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette=4) +
  coord_polar(theta="y") +
  xlim(c(2, 4)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  labs(title = "Regional Distribution of Ad Reach",
       subtitle = "Overall distribution for all ads studied")+
  theme(
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y  = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x  = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_text(color=txt_col, size=8, hjust = 0.4),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y.left = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = bg, color = bg),
    panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
    panel.border=element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust=0,size=24, color=txt_col,lineheight=.8, face="bold", margin=margin(0,0,0,0)),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust=0,size=14, color=txt_col, margin=margin(5,0,20,0)),
    plot.title.position = "plot",
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust=.5, margin=margin(20,0,0,0), size=8, color=txt_col, face="bold"),
    plot.background = element_rect(color=bg, fill=bg),
    plot.margin = margin(30,30,30,30),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "none"
  )
```

This is the picture it produces

[image]

How can I get rid of the 2.0 ... 4.0 on the left hand side and the 0.00/1 ...0.75 around the donut?

Thank you!

Comment: change `axis.text = element_text(color=txt_col, size=8, hjust = 0.4),` to `axis.text = element_blank(),`

Answer (score 0):

As @Allan Cameron says in the comments, `axis.text = element_blank()`resolves the issue.